# Weird spring boot scheduler behavior - don't work with lazy initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have bizarre scheduler behavior in my spring boot application. I run SB 2.6.7 and java 17.
My code

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfigurerConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    
    @Value("${schedule.pool}")
    private int DYNO_CORES;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        var taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(DYNO_CORES * 4);
        taskScheduler.initialize();
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
    }

       
    @Bean
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor() {
        var executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("bg_tasks_");
        executor.setConcurrencyLimit(UNBOUNDED_CONCURRENCY);//these jobs are mainly IO-bound, so let's not set a limit for now
        return executor;
    }
}
```

And my class with one task.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class NoPrimaryServiceTasks {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 1000 )
    public void checkBacklogSize() {
        log.info("logzzz");
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work.
But when I paste `context.getBean(NoPrimaryServiceTasks.class);` in main method everything works.
How to solve it without this workaround?

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.ScheduledBeanLazyInitializationExcludeFilter - also this class doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone added into our codebase this code :)

```
for ( String name : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames() ) {
    beanFactory.getBeanDefinition( name ).setLazyInit( true );
        }
```